# Float left without breaking into a second div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to show all my divs in single row. Currently it breaks to second row when it reach end of the parent div. I tried adding clear both attribute, then it will show all in single column.

I don't want to add fixed width to my parent div. And it's ok to have a horizontal scrollbar. Any solutions?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2yv9jrz/)

[image]

**One code block example**

```
<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

.report-body .report-single {
    width: 150px;
    float: left:
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Please tag your version of Bootstrap. Also, avoid floats. There are better ways.

Comment: Why aren't you using a table? This is what they're for.

Comment: I need to design a bit. It's hard to style tables

Comment: The content of your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g2yv9jrz/ does not appear to have anything to do with what your screenshot shows.

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```css
.report-body{

  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:auto;

}
.report-body .report-single {
    width: 150px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="report-body">


<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-single mr-2 float-left">
    <div class="report-header">
        Medical 1
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color4">
        <p class="mb-0">4A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$25</p>
    </div>
    <div class="report-body-sm key-div-color1">
        <p class="mb-0">2A</p>
        <p class="mb-0">$5</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```